# I cannot find the iATS configurations page

Tags: iats

We are using CiviCRM 5.58.1 on WordPress 6.2.2

We use iATS.  Someone else on this forum said there is a configuration page and they posted the below screenshot.  However, I cannot find this page anywhere on my CiviCRM install. I feel this screenshot is outdated.  Can someone please direct me to the new page so I can update our iATS configurations.
Thank you

[image]

Menu not showing iATS settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot shows the edit form for a specific recurring contribution with IATS (which you get to by going to the Contact, Contributions tab, Recurring Contributions sub-tab, then Edit). The general IATS configuration is at Administer - CiviContribute - IATS Payment Settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my post to show a screenshot of the menu.  As you can see, there is not any thing about iATS Payment settings under CiviCrontribute. Could you maybe share the direct link to it?  Maybe my menu isn't updating. I looking under the recurring payments tab  like you said and it looks nothing like the screenshot.  We are indeed using iATS,, but i am not seeing these  configuration pages anywhere.  Contributors are not getting their receipts for recurring donations and we are hoping to fix this when we find the iATS configurations.

Comment: civicrm/admin/contribute/iatssettings is where you set the emails to always, never or per contribution be sent.

Comment: For each individual recurring contribution, you should see an edit link beside it. If you don't, maybe you don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: That url is giving me a 404.  My urls look more like this.  wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fcontribute&reset=1

Comment: I have full permissions.  I know where the edit link is to edit recurring payments. I am saying it looks nothing like the screenshot above and what you say I should be seeing there.  For some reason, my iATS configuration appear to be missing.

Comment: Yes, sounds like something is wrong with your IATS. Is it up to date? Might want to try disabling and re-enabling it, but I would definitely note your payment processor and scheduled job settings before you do that (I don't think they should be changed, but better to be careful). If not, maybe uninstall and reinstall.